# Why can't I spoof Facebook with my own DNS server?

Tags: dns, subdomain, spoofing

Reading a lot about servers, load balancing and similar topics, a question came to mind.

DNS servers are servers which gives you the IP for a given domain name. Is there a "dictator" knowing all the valid DNS servers in the world? If I want to make a DNS server, and someone requests a website it doesn't have. How would it know which other DNS to redirect the request to? What if I tell facebook.com to have a spoof IP, and everyone getting the IP from my DNS server would be communicating with a spoof facebook server? Obviously, this isn't how it works (at least not at a big degree), because then someone would have done it already to attack hundreds of people.

When one registers a domain, one has to specify the name server for that domain. What happens during this process? Is a request sent to this DNS server to notify it there is a new domain to save in the database? If so, how can anyone own the top domains like .com? And why cannot I for example make my own top domain name if I can make my own DNS server?

After looking at nginx as a load balancing system, I'm starting to wonder a bit. Is it so that a request to http://www.google.com/ works like this? The computer asks a DNS server for the IP address for google.com, and then requests it? This will only be one IP, and all requests to Google ends up at this one server? And then this IP will be connected to a nginx server, or a more basic hardware unit to route the request internally to other servers? So all requests go to one server before it redirects the request to a data center?

After looking up google.com, it says the name servers are ns1.google.com etc.. But what is the point of them, if you need a different name server to get to ns1.google.com in the first place?

Obviously what I've written doesn't make sense, because if it were true, the web as a whole would be unusable because of people exploiting the possibilities for malicious causes. And I can't imagine how ONE server could handle ALL the requests thrown at google.com.

I've tried searching Google, but all I get is theoretical explanations that led me to where I am now. It would have been great if someone would point me to some articles that explain this thoroughly, and hopefully a lot of other people will find this question useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone can run a DNS server, but the challenge is getting someone to use it. Normally the DNS server IP is provided as a DHCP option or is statically assigned. If you can get someone to use your server, you can return any IP for any hostname, including creating new top-level domains (subject to any filtering at the client, of course. Web browsers might have difficulty with a new TLD, for example). Note that with DNSSEC, this will eventually change, as the name record will be digitally signed and your server won't be able to fake the signature exactly.

DNS servers operate in a tree. When one server receives a request for a domain it does not control, it forwards the request on to another DNS server. The other DNS server may be the one which returns the IP (this is called the authoritative server), or it may return a NS record which points to another server which then must be queried. The [DNS root servers](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/servers) provide for resolving TLDs.

A DNS server does not need to always return the same IP for a given name. It may choose to return a different IP based on region, client IP, or even per-request. This is the most typical way to load balance. Multiple DNS servers can also load balance the DNS requests by using anycast routing, where many servers share the same public IP and traffic is routed to them randomly by publishing multiple routes for the same IP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So Iana has somehow been chosen to administrate the domain name system, much like Firefox and Internet Explorer "have been chosen by the people" to be "internet". It's just that everybody uses their technology, and so it became the standard?

Comment: And so the ISP name servers redirect your request to Ianas root servers which puts Iana in charge of the TLDs? And you need to get people to use YOUR DNS-server instead of the ISPs to be able to control the domain lookup yourself? And this root servers list is public, so I can use it myself on my DNS server if my server doesn't know the IP?

Comment: Yes. Not so much as "chosen" as just that is how it has developed. Note that the root servers never answer a request directly. They always will be delegating to another server.

Comment: Maybe this is another question that should be posted separately, but how do you enable the DNS server to route the request randomly to different IPs? Does the TLD .com-server redirect the DNS request to one of the four name servers you can specify, so that those four can decide which IP to give the client?

Comment: In that case, does this mean that there are essentially four "entry servers" to the Google servers? ns1.google.com, ..., ns4.google.com?

Comment: Yes, Google has 4 servers. Routing just depends on the order in which records are returned. This is controlled in the DNS server.

Comment: So the TLD DNS server redirects the request to either of the four Google DNS servers randomly, and then the Google server returns a IP. (And then this IP is cached by each client so it connects to this same IP every time.)

Comment: But how would the TLD .com DNS server know what the IP of ns1.google.com is?

Comment: Because it is stored in a database. This is why you have to register domain names. The DNS server will have to do an additional lookup to find the IP for `ns1.google.com`. The `.com` server must know the NS IP. Part of registering as the nameserver for `google.com` is adding the `A` recods with IPs for the nameservers you register.

Comment: Aha, so the IPs are defined in the TLD .com DNS server. It's just written as a domain name as well so it's easier to remember. Thanks a lot for your help in clarifying this! I'm currently reading about anycast and how to use it.